# Push Array Items Into Another Array's Existing Objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, object, multidimensional-array, push

**Objective:** push one array into another array's *existing* objects instead of creating new objects.

I've tried several things and failed.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ibuprofen/5e4yrcL9/8/

**Console output of the current fiddle:**

```
arrayOne = [
  {
  itemOne: 'valueOne',
  itemTwo: 'valueTwo'
  },
  {
  itemOne: 'valueOne',
  itemTwo: 'valueTwo'
  },
  {
  itemOne: 'value1',
  itemTwo: 'value2'
  }
];
```

**Objective:**

```
arrayOne = [
  {
  itemOne: 'valueOne',
  itemTwo: 'valueTwo',
  itemThree: 'value1'
  },
  {
  itemOne: 'valueOne',
  itemTwo: 'valueTwo',
  itemThree: 'value2'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it isn't entirely clear what you are trying to do, here is some code that *might* help you find a solution to your challenge.

```js
arrayOne = [{
  itemOne: 'valueOne',
  itemTwo: 'valueTwo'
}, {
  itemOne: 'valueOne',
  itemTwo: 'valueTwo'
}];

arrayTwo = [{
  itemOne: 'value1',
  itemTwo: 'value2'
}];

const obj = arrayTwo[0];
const values = Object.values(obj);

const result = arrayOne.map((obj, index) => {
  obj.itemThree = values[index];
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```